# Как поменять содержимое двух элементов с одним ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача такая, есть группа элементов, у которых один ID, нужно поменять их содержимое местами, как это можно сделать?
Не могу понять, как сравнивать один ID с другим и делать подмену содержимого
Есть такой код:

```html
<div class="start" id="firstID">
  <p>One</p>
</div>
<div class="end" id="firstID">
  <p>Two</p>
</div>
<div class="start" id="secondID">
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
<div class="end" id="secondID">
  <p>Four</p>
</div>
```

Должно получиться следующее:

```html
<div class="start" id="firstID">
  <p>Two</p>
</div>
<div class="end" id="firstID">
  <p>One</p>
</div>
<div class="start" id="secondID">
  <p>Four</p>
</div>
<div class="end" id="secondID">
  <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

Пробовал записывать содержимое в переменные и вставлять в элементы, но вставляется только первое значение

Comment: одинаковый id - это ГРУБЕЙШАЯ ошибка :((

Comment: у же классы есть с ним рабоатйте

Comment: @humster_spb можно поинтересоваться почему? поменял на классы, но интересно, в чем такое различие для хранения переменных

Comment: Одинаковый `id` может быть только 1 на странице, почитайте про `id` и `class`, для чего они нужны.

Comment: @user324358, потому что такие стандарты: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = () => {
    const Y = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).filter(v => v.id == 'aw');


    for (const el of Y) {
        el.innerHTML = "awdawd";
        console.log(el.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: Угу, вижу, меняет содержимое на заданное содержимое, а как добиться такого результата, чтобы содержимое контейнеров менялись местами друг с другом?

One Two Three Four → Two One Four Three

Comment: [ у вас же есть классы еще с ними оперируйте